# How to tell yeoman to scaffold javascript vs. coffee files

Tags: configuration, coffeescript, scaffolding, yeoman

I was wondering if there is a way (i.e. configuration) where we can tell yeoman or the generator to scaffold .js files or .coffee files.

I'm currently using angular-generator and whenever I try to "yo angular:controller ctrlName", I get ctrlName.coffee. I figured this could be a default setting.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Best,
Quan

Answer (score 1):

The Angular generator should offer scaffolding in .js by default, but has .coffee available with the `--coffee` flag: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#coffeescript

> For generators that output scripts, the --coffee option will output CoffeeScript instead of JavaScript.
>   ...
>   A project can mix CoffeScript and JavaScript files.

Comment: Thanks, Max. It's good we have the --coffee option. As it turned out, the issue I had was that I had a .coffee file in my app/scripts folder. This is why angular-generator generates .coffee files by default. Once I removed the file, I was able to see my .js files generated correctly.